Transistor biasing on switch state change - DFPlayer mini
Relative newbie here.
I'm looking for some guidance on a DFPlayer project. We are looking to update this musical tracer project:
https://www.zeroday.camp/musical-tracer/
Basically music plays when a stylus contacts a conductive path (in effect, a switch) and stops when the pen stylus is lifted.
I know this is trivial using a microprocessor but it seems to me to be way overkill.
Grounding ADKey1 through a 33K resistor (3x100K in parallel)  makes that button  play/pause (see diagram, obviously not a complete one). Holding the switch closed has no additional effect. Tested, works great. So that's the function I need.
What I'm thinking is there should be a way to , in effect, ground that pin every time the stylus changes state. Hopefully that makes sense. So power on-->stylus down--> ground pin (Starts playing)-->stylus up-ground pin (pauses) etc.
I'm assuming I'd replace SW2 with a transistor. So I just need to activate it every time the stylus "switch" changes state I'm at a bit of a loss for the rest.
Of note is the Busy pin, it's at 3.3V  when the music IS NOT playing and 0V when it is. So a possible solution is an XOR gate (if either the stylus "switch" or the Busy bin are high then bias the transistor) but again , that seems overly complicated.

TIA
Marc
